# Parse data from a postgreSQL database using C++

Tags: postgresql

I am new in c++ and a want to parse data from a column of a PostgreSQL database and store them in a vector. I do not want to parse the whole database.

Has anyone any ideas?

Thank you in advance

Comment: SO is not a tutorial. I recommend you find and read one first.

Comment: Ok, I have searched tutorials, but there is not anything which can answer to my question. Which tutorial do you propose to me through which my question may be answered?

Comment: Maybe you just phrased your question wrong. What did you try and what part of it did not do what you expected? Are you having issues fetching data from database? If yes, what kind. Is storing data in a vector an issue?